# How to load dynamic column and rows from http call (both column and record should be dynamic) in ag-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

i have requirement like user will click on any table name then i have to render respective data in ag-grid.

i am using angular js 1.x.

i tried all the ways

```
$scope.gridOptions = {};
$scope.loadTableInGrid = function (tablename) {
    $http.post($scope.url + "/getPagingRecordImportedTable", { 'dbname': $stateParams.dbname, 'tableName': tablename, 'pageNumber': 1 }).success(

        function (response) {

            $scope.names = response.records;
            $scope.mdata = response.metadata;

            console.log(response.records);
            console.log(response.metadata);

            var  columnsize = 0;
            for (var obj in $scope.mdata) {
                if ($scope.mdata[obj]['columnsize'] > 20) {
                    columnsize = 20;
                } else {
                    columnsize = $scope.mdata[obj]['columnsize'];
                }

                $scope.columnDefs.push({
                    "headerName": $scope.mdata[obj]['columnname'],
                    "field": $scope.mdata[obj]['columnname']
                });
            }


            var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
            alert(gridDiv);
            new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, $scope.gridOptions);
            $scope.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs( $scope.columnDefs);
            $scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData(response.records);
            $scope.gridOptions.api.refreshView();



            console.log("-----------Data received");
        }).error(function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    } else {
        $scope.reset();
        $scope.resetGridTableName();

    }
    console.log(tablename);
};
```

as per table name i have to load column and record both dynamically in grid .
but it is always saying "loading" and nothing to render.

if any example is there please refer or refactor my code.

Answer (score 0):

I can see 1 if and 2 else statement in your code... You are missing something..?

Anyhow. Angular ajax method returns a Promise, so it should be used with .then/.catch instead of .success/.error

I would have written it more like this: (untested) (beware ES6 arrow fn and const)

```
$scope.gridOptions = {};
$scope.loadTableInGrid = tablename => {
    const url = $scope.url + "/getPagingRecordImportedTable"
    const formData = {
        dbname: $stateParams.dbname,
        tableName: tablename,
        pageNumber: 1
    }

    console.log(tablename);

    $http.post(url, formData)
    .then( response => {
        $scope.names = response.records;
        $scope.mdata = response.metadata;

        console.log(response.records);
        console.log(response.metadata);

        var  columnsize = 0;
        for (var obj in $scope.mdata) {
            if ($scope.mdata[obj]['columnsize'] > 20) {
                columnsize = 20;
            } else {
                columnsize = $scope.mdata[obj]['columnsize'];
            }

            $scope.columnDefs.push({
                headerName: $scope.mdata[obj]['columnname'],
                field: $scope.mdata[obj]['columnname']
            });
        }

        var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
        alert(gridDiv);
        new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, $scope.gridOptions);
        $scope.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs( $scope.columnDefs]);
        $scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData(response.records);
        $scope.gridOptions.api.refreshView();

        console.log("-----------Data received");

    }).catch( err => {
        console.log( "Error: ", err )
    })
};
```